# ADT says unforunately App has stopped after click event used for starting a new activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

My first activity code is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button mainActLoginBtn, mainActCreateBtn;
EditText mainActUserEdt, mainActPswEdt;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mainActLoginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    mainActCreateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    mainActUserEdt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
    mainActPswEdt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt2);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tview);
    mainActLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String userString = mainActUserEdt.getText().toString();
            String pswString = mainActPswEdt.getText().toString();
            if (userString.contentEquals("Dev")
                    && pswString.contentEquals("1234")) {
                tv.setText("Welcome " + userString
                        + "Click Proceed to further process");
                Intent successAct = new Intent("com.example.a_m_s.INTRO");
                startActivityForResult(successAct, 0);

            }
        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The app does not run successfully first window is shown which is a login window after entering the login credentials and clicking on the Login Button the error is generated in Android Emulator
I am not able to figure out what can be the problem if more reference code is required please ask for it.

Comment: post your log cat error

Comment: post the stacktrace and `INTRO` class and check the manifest for activity entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Intent successAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this,INTRO.class);
                startActivity(successAct);
```

**Example:**

```
mainActLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String userString = mainActUserEdt.getText().toString();
            String pswString = mainActPswEdt.getText().toString();
            if (userString.contentEquals("Dev")
                    && pswString.contentEquals("1234")) {
                tv.setText("Welcome " + userString
                        + "Click Proceed to further process");
                 Intent successAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this,INTRO.class);
                    startActivity(successAct);

            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: @user3114217 post your manifest and also what are you entered in `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

Besides writing `startActivityForResult(successAct, 0);` you need to write `startActivity(successAct);`

```
mainActLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String userString = mainActUserEdt.getText().toString();
        String pswString = mainActPswEdt.getText().toString();
        if (userString.contentEquals("Dev")
                && pswString.contentEquals("1234")) {
            tv.setText("Welcome " + userString
                    + "Click Proceed to further process");
             Intent successAct = new Intent("com.example.a_m_s.INTRO");
                startActivity(successAct);

        }
    }

});
```